# Iterating over nested JSON string in typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a test nested JSON string.

```
const testString = `{
  "object1": {
    "5": [
      {
        "id": "A2OKPZ5S9F78PD",
        "rate": "2",
        "item": "item",
        "status": "status"
      }
    ]
  },
  "type": "LIVE_EVENT"
}`;

const model = JSON.parse(testString);
Object.values(model.object1).forEach((obj) =>
  obj.foreach((innerObj) => console.log(innerObj))
);
```

As you can see above I am trying to parse this as JSON and iterate over. The problem which I am facing during JSON.parse the inner object assumes the type undefined and foreach can not be applied on it. Can some one please help ?

Comment: `(obj || []).forEach`

Comment: Tried changing to this Object.values(model.object1).forEach(obj => (obj || []).foreach(innerObj => console.log(innerObj)));   Still did not work

Comment: it's forEach not foreach, still the same?

Comment: Still does now work. Tried this. Object.values(model.object1).forEach(obj => (obj || []).forEach(innerObj => console.log(innerObj)));

Comment: `model.object1` is indeed an object, so you need to iterate its properties https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Comment: It says it does not allow forEach on undefined.

Comment: @diedu I did not understand

Comment: I guess @diedu pointed out the problem. You need to use Object.values(obj) to get the array so you can use forEach on it.

Comment: Well I am using Object.values. And Its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON <s>is</s> was invalid (before an edit) due to an extra comma after the status key/value pair and `forEach()` has an uppercase E. Also, as discussed in the comments below it seems you need to cast the inner `obj` to be of a type that understands `forEach()`:

```js
const testString = `{"object1":{"5":[{"id":"A2OKPZ5S9F78PD","rate":"2","item":"item","status":"status"}]},"type":"LIVE_EVENT"}`;
const model = JSON.parse(testString);
Object.values(model.object1).forEach((obj) =>
  (obj as any).forEach((innerObj) => console.log(innerObj))
);
```

Comment: I am running the same code you pasted here on typescript. It says forEach can not be applied over undefined.

Comment: Check if your `JSON.parse(testString)` is actually parsing the json, i.e., log the `model` variable.

Comment: @DarkShadows Can you share SS of that?

Comment: Make sure that when you run the code above, you're actually having exactly the same `testString` as I do, because when I run locally it works.

Comment: { object1: { '5': [ [Object] ] }, type: 'LIVE_EVENT' } This is what i get after JSON.parse

Comment: error TS2339: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'unknown'. This is the exact error upon applying.

Comment: @DarkShadows if what you are getting is a typescript compile time error you could try casting the value so it doesn't complain `model.object1 as Array`

Comment: Try `(obj as any).forEach((innerObj) => console.log(innerObj))`

Comment: @LuísRamalho Yes (obj as any) worked. Thank you very much. Can you update your answer so that I can mark as accepted.

Comment: Awesome, done. You should find the actual type of `obj` and not use `any`, maybe Array as @diedu pointed out. An array of the type of object that you have.